# Discord.py Como puedo hacer una matriz de 4 por 4 con botones pero esos botones tiene que tener interacciónes

Tags: python, discord.py

Como puedo hacer una matriz de 4 por 4con botones pero necesito que esos botones tengan interacción....

Mi objetivo es que cuando presiones los botones edite el emblema de arriba con los botones que voy presionando.

code:

```py
class Yamila(discord.ui.View):
     def __init__(self):
                   super().__init__()
     @discord.ui.button(label='1',style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
     async def uno(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
         pass
     @discord.ui.button(label='2',style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
     async def dos(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
         pass
         
     @discord.ui.button(label='3',style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
     async def tres(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
         pass
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dependiendo si se trata de markdown, un embed, una imagen o un componente, deberás editarlo a travéz del objeto Message, que representa al mensaje y podrás obtener usando interaction.message.